# the rpc call doesn't workd after adding spring4gwt

Tags: spring, gwt, configuration, spring-4-gwt

To integrate spring in my gwt application i added spring4gwt and i followed the tutorial in  [SimpleRPCExample](https://code.google.com/p/spring4gwt/wiki/SimpleRPCExample). But it doesn't work, however everything in configuration and code seems OK.

So this what i put in application context to scan servlets

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.protid.prosa.server" />
```

I tagged my **SaService** interface with **@RemoteServiceRelativePath("sab/travaux")** and the 
**SaServiceImpl** Service with **@Service("travaux")**

The user interface is loaded but the rpc call doesn't work. Can any body tell me where is the mistake i did, or what is the best approach to integer spring with gwt. Thank you,

And this is how i added the servlet to my web.xml

```
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-clas‌​s>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/prosa/sab/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: and this is how i added the servlet to  my web.xml 

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/prosa/sab/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: what error are you getting ? do you see anything unusual in the server log ?

Comment: have you actually added `springframework` to your project? the `ContextLoaderListener` to your `web.xml` ?